# Mistake in fetching childNodes of HTML table

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm a bit confused regarding HTML DOM. I'm trying to get the rows of a particular `<table>` so that I can interate through them.

HTML MARKUP:

```
    <table style="width:70%" id="PersonalInfoExtendedModel_Table" >
      <tr>
      <td><span id="PersonalInfoExtendedModel_FirstName">@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.FirstName)</span></td>
      <td><span id="PersonalInfoExtendedModel_JobLocation">@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.JobLocation)</span></td>

      </tr>

      <tr>
      <td><span id="PersonalInfoExtendedModel_MiddleName">@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.MiddleName)</span></td>
      <td><span id="PersonalInfoExtendedModel_StateOfResidence">@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.StateOfResidence)</span></td>

      </tr>

      <tr>
      <td><span id="PersonalInfoExtendedModel_LastName">@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.LastName)</span></td>
      <td><span id="PersonalInfoExtendedModel_SSN">@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.SSN)</span></td>

      </tr>

      <tr>
      <td><span id="PersonalInfoExtendedModel_Suffix">@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Suffix)</span></td>
      <td><span id="PersonalInfoExtendedModel_USDriversLicenseNumber">@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.USDriversLicenseNumber)</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span id="PersonalInfoExtendedModel_USDriversLicenseState">@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.USDriversLicenseState)</span></td>

  </tr>

  <tr>
  <td><span id="PersonalInfoExtendedModel_DOB_Date">@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.DOB_Date)</span>&nbsp;<span id="PersonalInfoExtendedModel_DOB_Month">@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.DOB_Month)</span>&nbsp;<span id="PersonalInfoExtendedModel_DOB_Year">@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.DOB_Year)</span></td>
  <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

What I've done in JS and Jquery:

```
var rows = document.getElementById(model + "_Table").childNodes;
```

The above line got me some weird childNodes. I got rows[] having a 'text' child, and a `<table>` child!!
So I also tried:

```
var rows = document.getElementById(model + "_Table").childNodes[1].childNodes;
```

This second line gave the following childNodes as seen in Google Chrome while debugging:
0: HTMLTableRowElement
1: Text
2: HTMLTableRowElement
3: Text
4: HTMLTableRowElement
5: Text
6: HTMLTableRowElement
7: Text
8: HTMLTableRowElement
9: Text

Why did'nt the 2nd line get JUST the rows?? And why didn't the 1st line itself just fetch all the rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The browser adds a `<tbody>` which is why you can't acess the `<tr>` directly.
2. The childnodes "Text"  refer to the whitespaces between your rows. Just remove the linebreaks and you are fine.

I prefer using `querySelectorAll`:

```
document.querySelectorAll("#"+model + "_Table tr")
```

but if you are concerned about IE6 users, your selection would look like this:

```
var rows = document.getElementById(model + "_Table").rows;
```

Comment: Use `qSA()` because it is so very compatible and efficient by comparison. NOT.

Comment: @ Christoph: Good option if the OP is working in standards mode with only recent versions of IE.

Comment: @PointedEars http://caniuse.com/#search=querySelector. Unless you are living in China, your browser will most likely support this. (IE6 ~1%, IE7~2%)

Comment: Even caniuse.com can be wrong, and it certainly is not detailed enough. The problem with `qSA()` is – its inherent inefficiency aside – that each layout engine supports a different subset of CSS. In this case, if `qSA()` is supported, it probably works (only ID and element selectors here). But it is not a good idea for a general approach.

Comment: well, I would consider IE as the weak link and IE9 supports all css3 selectors, so i guess the differences are down to some edge-cases. http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/selectors-api-testsuite/ If you are arguing that way, then you probably have to stick to standards from 10years ago...have fun.

Answer (score 2):

> The above line got me some weird childNodes. I got rows[] having a 'text' child, and a `<table>` child!!

I suspect you're seeing a `tbody` child, not a `table` child. All tables have at least one [`tbody` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-tbody-element.html#the-tbody-element). If you don't supply one in your markup, the browser will add it for you (in standards mode; I don't know what happens in quirks mode as I never work in quirks mode). The table may also have a `Text` node for the whitespace in it. You mentioned Chrome; you can use the "Elements" tab of the dev tools to explore the DOM created by the browser in response to your markup.

If you want to get the `tr` elements from the table, if there are no nested tables, you can do this:

```
var rows = document.getElementById(model + "_Table").getElementsByTagName('tr');
```

Alternately, you can use the [`rows` property](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-table-element.html#dom-table-rows), which gives you the table's own rows (and not the rows of nested tables):

```
var rows = document.getElementById(model + "_Table").rows;
```

Note that the `rows` on the `table` element will include all rows in `tbody`, `thead`, and `tfoot` child elements of the table. If you *only* want the `rows` of a particular `tbody`, each `tbody` has its own [`rows` property](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-tbody-element.html#dom-tbody-rows).

Comment: gEBTN() is not a good idea here (potentially incompatible method call); `rows` is.  Also, [a `table` element object has a `tBodies` `NodeList` property](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-64060425) that provides easy access to the `tbody` element objects, if necessary.

Comment: @PointedEars: What do you mean by `getElementsByTagName` is an "incompatible method call"? Even IE6 has it, and it's been [defined in a standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-DOM-Level-1/level-one-core.html#ID-745549614) since at least 1998. I think `rows` is probably a better idea for the OP (or `querySelectorAll` if they stick to standards mode and recent versions of IE), but not because of any incompatibility issues with `getElementsByTagName`.

Comment: You need to differentiate between `Document::getElementsByTagName()` and `Element::getElementsByTagName()`. I remember MSHTML in particular to support the latter.  Might have been an older version, though.

Comment: @PointedEars: Note that the link to the DOM1 standard from 1998 above **was** to `Element#getElementsByTagName`. And I tested it (not `document.getElementsByTagName`) on IE6 before posting.

Comment: I *know* it was specified in DOM Level 1 Core, but there is the specification, and there is reality. Good if it works for you in IE6; *might* have been a problem in IE/MSHTML 5.5 only, then. In any case, there is no need to take that risk and the inefficiency. (That should be "*not* support the latter" in my previous comment, BTW.)